# Image of $x$ under canonical projection is root of polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $K[x]$ where $K$ is a field. Let $I$ be the ideal generated in $K[x]$ by $M(x)$. Let $\alpha$ be the image of $x$ in the field $J= K[x] / \langle M(x) \rangle$. Then $\alpha$ is a root of the equation $M(x)=0$.

I am trying to understand this by going back to basics and am running in to difficulties. Let $\pi: K[x] \to J$ be the canonical homomorphism.

Assume $M(x)=x^2+1$ and $K[x]= \mathbb{R}[x]$. My goal is to show that $\pi(x)=i$.

From my understanding, $\pi$ will map $x$ to the set $\{ x + \langle x^2 +1 \rangle \}$. I know that in $J$ we must have that $x^2 +1 =0$ and so $x^2=-1$ and so $x=i$. However, I am not sure how to relate this to the set $\{x + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle \}$, i.e. is $i$ the representative of  $\{x + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle \}$ ?

Comment: More or less. You should understand that $\Bbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$ is *isomorphic* to $\Bbb{C}$, not *equal* to it. Under this isomorphism the coset $x + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$ does correspond to the complex number $i$, but they are not the same thing. Also, you are mixing up the notation, because $x$ is not an element of $J$. What you have in $J$ is that $(x + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle)^2 + (1 + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle) = \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$, i.e. $\pi(x)^2 = \pi(-1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\pi(x)$ is not literally $i$ because $i$ is in $\mathbb C$ and $\pi(x)$ is in $K[x]/\langle M(x)\rangle$.  It's not correct to say "$x^2 = -1$ and so $x=i$."
In any field in which $X^2 + 1$ has a root, it has two roots.  You can, if you want, call one of them $i$, but that's just a label.
If $r = x + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle$, then $$r^2 + 1 = x^2 + 1 + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle = 0 + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$$ 
so $r$ is a root of $X^2 + 1$.